# ARIMA modelling for more than 1 time series

Tags: python, time-series, analytics, data-science, arima

So my data looks like this

```
           Date1 Date2 Date 3.....Date N
Instance1
Instance2
.
.
.
```

I don't want to build an ARIMA model for only Instance1. I want a universal model that takes all the instances into consideration. I found a lot of examples that show me how to fit it for

```
         Date1 Date2 Date 3.....Date N
Instance1
```

but none for all instances

Comment: Answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/estimating-same-model-over-multiple-time-series

Answer (score 4):

If you believe your time-series are correlated and you want to take those correlations into account in your forecast/simulation, you should look at vector auto-regression models (VAR). Here are a couple options in python:

[StatsModels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html)

[PyFlux](https://pyflux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/var.html?highlight=var)

If you don't believe they are correlated, then there's no reason you can't just loop through each time-series and apply an ARIMA model one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, on a different note when I'm trying to use ARIMA I keep getting "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects" . I am using a series with the Index as Date-Time and values which are float. Any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome.  Regarding your new question, I think this qualifies as a separate post, I'd just be guessing with what I know at the moment.  It would be helpful to see an example of the data you're using, the libraries, and a code example.